# Compiler says "Cannot create a generic array" although array isn't generic

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I created the class `Queue` with

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Queue <T>{
        private LinkedList<T> list;

        public Queue() {
            list = new LinkedList<>();
        }

        ...
}
```

I also created the class `Cinema`, which has a private field of an array of `Queue<String>`.

```
public class Cinema {
    private Queue<String>[] arr;
    
    public Cinema() {
        arr = new Queue<String>[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            arr[i] = new Queue<String>();
    }

        ...
}
```

However, the line `arr = new Queue<String>[10];` throws a compilation error, saying `Cannot create a generic array of Queue<String>`. But as I understand it the array isn't generic, as its generic type is defined to be `String`.

When I change the line to

```
arr = new Queue[10];
```

the code works again, although it still gives me a warning saying `Type safety: The expression of type Queue[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Queue<String>[]`. So I don't understand why the original doesn't work.

Comment: The short answer is that arrays and generics just never mix well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But as I understand it the array isn't generic, as its generic type is defined to be String.

Different meanings of the same word. What the compiler means is: There are `<>` and/or type vars involved anywhere in the array type. Which you can't do.

Arrays are low-level constructs that you don't use except for classes that define new collection concepts. You aren't doing that here. Ditch the array, make a `List<Queue<String>>` instead.

If you insist on using arrays, you're doing it: `arr = new Queue[10]`. Yes, this gets a warning. The only thing you can do is live with it, or use `@SuppressWarnings`. Arrays and generics don't mix very well. Hence, don't - use `List<Queue<String>>` instead.